# Check if TimeSpan falls in Daylight Saving transition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, timespan

I have flight arrival time and the flight departure time. I have to check if the flight time falls in the daylight saving transition (Equinox Transition). If the hour is forward I need to add an hour in flight time else if the hour is reverted I need to deduct an hour from flight time.

In `TimeZoneInfo` class we do have `IsDaylightSavingTime` but it only says either if the time is in Daylight saving or not.

I need to check that my timespan is either effected by DayLight Saving Transition or not.

*Update1*: The transition is observed in March and November but the date changes every year so I can't hard code any date. I need to get the specific date of the year at which the EQUINOX will occur.

*Update2*: Datetime is local not UTC, as the flight arrival and departure are from the same airport.

Data: 
Flight Departure Time : 19 March 2019 23:00
Flight Arrival Time : 20 March 2019 08:00
Flight Time : 7 Hours but due to EQUINOX its 8 Hours as the hour was forward at
20 March 2019 05:58

Comment: Use UTC for departure and arrival time, then convert them to local time separately.

Comment: What about using NodaTime to do this? Getting the `Duration` between two `ZonedDateTime`s should be quite simple.

Comment: @ElmoDev001 I need to check when the EQUINOX going to occur this year and then I have to check either my time span falls init or not.

Comment: @Sweeper for simplicity we can say there are no Different Time Zone. The time zone remains same

Comment: @Jackboys Still, you should use a `ZonedDateTime` here, because you are considering DST (if you are using NodaTime at all, that is). An `Instant` is also fine, but make sure you take into account of the timezone when parsing the string into an `Instant`.

Comment: It would really help if you could make this concrete with sample data. For example, we don't know whether you have the departure and arrive times as *local* times (which can be ambiguous) or in UTC (which can't). Note that if you only have local times, you're losing data anyway if you depart or arrive at an ambiguous time (during a fall-back transition). Note that DST transitions don't happen on the precise equinox generally - I would avoid mentioning the equinox unless that's genuinely important for your question, as otherwise it's confusing.

Comment: @JonSkeet the flight departs and arrives at the same airport so that why its safe to have the local time.

Comment: @Jackboys: No, that's not safe. If a flight departs at 1:20 and arrives at 1:40, that could be 20 minutes or 80 minutes. Fundamentally, if you only have the local time then for two hours of the year, those times are ambiguous. You are losing information - it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

The [GetAdjustmentRules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.getadjustmentrules?view=netframework-4.8) provide you the info you are looking for:

> Provides information about a time zone adjustment, such as the transition to and from daylight saving time.

Example of the output of the sample code in the above link:

```
W. Europe Standard Time Adjustment rules  
Start Date: Monday, January 01, 0001  
End Date: Friday, December 31, 9999  
Time Change: 1:00 hours  
Annual Start: The Last Sunday of March at 2:00 AM  
Annual End: The Last Sunday of October at 3:00 AM
```

Also the [IsInvalidTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isinvalidtime?view=netframework-4.8) say you if the specific value is invalid due to daylight transition.

You can convert it to a valid DateTime by using:

```
TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(id);

if (timeZone.IsInvalidTime(dateTime))
    dateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTime.ToUniversalTime(), timeZone);
```

Finally, my suggestion is to store and evaluate DateTime as UTC in order to avoid ambiguity. You can convert it to local time for GUI purpose only.

**EDIT:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981072/net-timezone-currenttimezone-getdaylightchanges-returns-wrong-dst-for-2005) is there an example of how to use GetAdjustmentRules.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I have checked the function but it returns incorrect data, as of my data its like
```{System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule}
    DateEnd: {12/31/2006 00:00:00}
    DateStart: {01/01/0001 00:00:00}
    DaylightDelta: {01:00:00}
    DaylightTransitionEnd: {System.TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime}
    DaylightTransitionStart: {System.TimeZoneInfo.TransitionTime}```

Comment: I want to get DST transition date time of current year

Comment: Have a look inside the DaylightTransitionStart struct. You have Month, Week and DayOfWeek. All data is there, you need just to put the pieces together.

Comment: In your first comment you are looking to a past daylight standard, valid up to 12/31/2006. You may have other AdjustmentRule in the array.

Comment: Have a look at this question where there is an example of how to use GetAdjustmentRules https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981072/net-timezone-currenttimezone-getdaylightchanges-returns-wrong-dst-for-2005